# Why are objects see through when rendered with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Why do I see through it.

[image]

[Blendfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XRQMFwmdYlYxe7S7fcoNx1Q1pzLhUSR7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome! This question could be improved with some extra clarity. Perhaps describe what you're trying to do, what objects are in your scene, what render settings you're using and any other information that may be relevant. You could also upload your .blend file so that we may crack it open ourselves and have a deeper look.

Comment: Without knowing the material setup it's hard to tell...

Comment: hey , i put the link

Comment: All of your lights are hidden in the viewport

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your materials, *Carbase* and *glasstint*, have the *Alpha* value in the *Principled BSDF* set to a value less than 1. Every value lower than 1 will make them not fully opaque. (Even the glass shouldn't use that for a proper transparency).

Comment: Thx ,  i'm new* to blender

Comment: @milkyway You're welcome, and as Allen commented above: your lights are disabled, just in case you're wondering why everything is dark except for the emissive materials.